# Can I track text change to an input field ONCE, not on every input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a basic text input field and, for data analytics purposes, I want to track every time a user edits the text in that field as they edit it. I have this code so far:

```
 var input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
 input.oninput = function (e) {
                   alert("changed"); 
                 }
```

The issue is that this fires every time the user deletes or adds a character, whereas  I only want to know one single time that they are changing the text in the text field. Is there a way to achieve this? I am new to jQuery and JavaScript so any direction would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) option `once: true`:

> `once`: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If `true`, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

**Please Note:** Internet Explorer yet to support this parameter characteristic.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  alert("changed"); 
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<input id="inputId"/>
```

Comment: Very nice, just be aware that the `options` arguments don't work in IE

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the event handler to fire once per element, then you need to remove the event handler the first time it runs:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
input.addEventListener('input', yourFunc);

function yourFunc(e) {
  alert("changed");
  this.removeEventListener('input', yourFunc);
}
```

Note the use of `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` instead of the outdated `oninput` property.

As you've tagged jQuery in the question you can also achieve it in this manner, using `one()`:

```
$('#inputId').one('input', function() {
  alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to bind to the `onchange` event instead: it is fired when the input value is "finalized" by the user, e.g. when he/she blurs from the field:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
input.addEventListener('change', (e) => console.log('changed', e.target.value));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove function when it call

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
input.oninput = function (e) {
                    alert("changed");
                    input.oninput = undefined;
                }
```

```html
<input id="inputId">
```